# Zxing scanner scans image, but returns NotFoundException when taken as a input file on Android

Tags: java, android, zxing

I am new to Android Programming. I am using Zxing Library to create a QR code and save it as a png file so that i can share it and the other user can consume it. QR code is generated properly but when I try to read the same it some times reads it properly but many a times gives NotFoundException.
Code that I have written to read the QR code from file is standard. not sure how to find out the issue.

```
        Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]));
        cursor.close();

        Bitmap bMap = null;
        try {
            bMap = decodeUri(selectedImage);
            int[] intbMapArray = new int[bMap.getWidth()*bMap.getHeight()]; 
            bMap.getPixels(intbMapArray, 0, bMap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight());
            LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap.getHeight(), bMap.getWidth(), intbMapArray); 
            BinaryBitmap binBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();

            Result result = null;
            result = reader.decode(binBitmap);
            if (genQRCodeUpdateFields(intent,result.getText())){
                ToQRCode.setImageBitmap(bMap);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | NotFoundException | ChecksumException | FormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to read code from "+ picturePath,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Reset();
        }
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Stack trace is null it just returns "com.google.zxing.NotFoundException"
I have realized that in  "MultiFormatReader.java" it comes out of for loop  and executes " throw NotFoundException.getNotFoundInstance();"  (i.e. as per design)  it did not understand that its a QRcode binarybitmap.

Comment: decode internal Method look likes below


 private Result decodeInternal(BinaryBitmap image) throws NotFoundException {
    if (readers != null) {
      for (Reader reader : readers) {
        try { return reader.decode(image, hints);
        } catch (ReaderException re) {
        }}}
    throw NotFoundException.getNotFoundInstance();
  }

Comment: I manually Increased the size of the Image file (by 200%) and it worked then the QR code was less complex. Is there any guidance on Image size so that the reader decode consistently. as few weeks back I had created a QR Code for which i had to reduce its size.

If any one knows about it then please share the info. I need it !!!! will keep playing around to see if i can deduce any thing.